# How do I call overloaded member function with cv-qualifier?

Tags: c++

I have been reading through the C++ standard and from there I found out that the cv-qualifiers are part of the function signature for member functions.

Consider the case below:

```
/******************************
* Function signature testing
*******************************/
class Signature
{   
public:
    void vSignature( void )
    {
        cout << "signature" << endl;        
    }

    void vSignature( void ) const 
    {
        cout << "constant signature" << endl;
    }
};

typedef void (Signature::*constFunc)( void ) const ;
int main(void)
{
    constFunc f = &Signature::vSignature;
    Signature s;
    s.vSignature();  //outputs 'signature'
    (s.*f)();        // outputs 'constant signature'
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, when I call vSignature in the 'ordinary' way, the non-const overload gets called. In order to 'force' the const overload to be used, I have to obtain the pointer to the vSignature function and cast it to the const overload.

Is there any other way to call the vSignature() const overload aside from the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any other way to call the vSignature() const overload aside from the above?

Yes. You can do this:

```
//first 
const Signature s;
s.vSignature(); //calls const function

//second
Signature s;
static_cast<const Signature &>(s).vSignature(); //calls const function

 //third
 void f(const Signature &s)
 { 
      s.vSignature(); //calls const function
 }

 Signature s;
 f(s);
```

The idea is : `const` functions get invoked on `const` object and `const` expression involving the object.

Comment: Shouldn't the second example be `const_cast<Signature const&>(s)` ?

Comment: @MSalters: Oops... I forgot the `const` keyword there. As for `const_cast`, static_cast would do the same thing.

Comment: And also for non-const objects, if it is the only function signature.

Comment: @Nawaz, static_cast would do the same thing but doesn't const_cast get more clearer/purposeful/narrowed intent?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. In any case, the cv-qualified version of a function should do the *exact same* thing as the non cv-qualified version, but should just be there for the sake of const-correctness.

Comment: Exactly. You should never need to force it one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know const member functions are only called on const objects, so if your object is non-const, it will call the non-const function.

Answer (score 0):

If the object calling the function is `const` then desired function will be called:

```
((const Signature&)s).vSignature();
```

Comment: I'd go with static_cast here. Even though it does the same thing (as the C-style cast) in this case, it will prevent an unsafe cast when someone decides to change the type of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The overload chosen depends on the type of the expression, not the underlying type of the object. Therefore you can just add the const with a cast:

```
const_cast<Signature const&>(s).vSignature();
```

This has the added advantage that the reader can easily spot what you're doing.